# How to convert Date String in specific format to ISO String

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have date string in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm aa` for example `2021-11-21 13:19 PM`
which i want to convert into ISOString

```
const event = new Date('2021-11-21 13:19 PM');
console.log(event.toISOString());
```

which gives error `'Invalid date'`
i tried with Date.parse, same issue.

Comment: If you're using 24 hour format, then no need of using AM/PM.

Comment: const event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');


console.log(event.toString());
    
console.log(event.toISOString());